# Apache multisite shows me only one website

Tags: php, .htaccess, webserver, apache2

I set up apache2 on my Ubuntu computer. I have two php websites, one in the `/var/www/html/a4` folder and one in the `/var/www/html/mad` folder. I activated the .conf files and disabled the default one from the sites-enabled folder. Each site has an .htaccess. Two strange things happen:

1. if I go to localhost/a4 I get error 404, whereas if I go to localhost I get site a4.
2. If I look for localhost/mad I am redirected to the index.php of the a4 site.

If I re-enable the 000-default.conf file everything works again, but at that point if I visit localhost/a4 or localhost/mad the document root is /a4/ or /mad/ and not '/' and this causes me problems in routing.

This is the a4 `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /a4/

RewriteRule ^(index\.php|mad(/.*)?)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^phpmyadmin(/.*)?$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Here the mad .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mad/

# Ignora le richieste per index.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^phpmyadmin(/.*)?$ - [L]

# Controlla se il file o la directory richiesta esistono
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Riscrivi tutte le altre richieste a index.php
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Here the a4.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName a4
    ServerAlias www.a4
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/a4

    <Directory /var/www/html/a4>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

here the mad.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName mad
    ServerAlias www.mad
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mad

    <Directory /var/www/html/mad>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

How can I solve this and display both sites correctly?

I have tried several times to enable file permissions and to disable and enable files from sites-available to sites-enabled by restarting the server but same result.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the two `.conf` files? Those are the ones that tell Apache which folder to look in when a request comes in

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the comment, I added both files.

Comment: Why would you be accessing either `localhost/a4` or `localhost/mad` to begin with? You just set up host names `a4` and `mad` via your vhost configuration - so why are you not using those to access these projects?

Comment: if I only type a4 or mad in the browser, the google search starts.

Comment: you need to add a4 and mad to your /etc/hosts file to stop the brower searching outside, i.e. `127.0.0.1 localhost mad a4`

Comment: works, but I need to add a "/" after the query. Is normal? i.e. mad/index/